# Accessing packages/extra downloaded content

Tags: android, package, billing, in-app

I am planning to use in-app billing to allow users to download additional data content in my app.

My question is how do I access it once its downloaded? I've seen things mentioned about packages before but i would want just data added not code? Would i have a new DB downloaded? Or maybe new data into an existing DB?

Thinking about that now, if it was a new DB, what would stop someone with a rooted phone just grabbing the new content and pirating/copying/uploading it to the web?

I don't mind people posting links to guides to these questions.

I mainly care about the new data and how I install it and then access it.

Comment: You need to mention what kind of data. If I understood correctly, you are allowing user to download music/video and store them in SD card? Please consider including more details, so that someone can answer it better. After any application download a content, it can be placed in any directory (You can use Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ) to keep the files in default directory

Comment: Well all sorts of data. Audio, video (though more likely to host this online) but mainly text, which is what I would be storing in the db.